# Crash when doing multi thread operation on SQLite database using Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, sqlite, qtconcurrent

I have a code which performs 3 async make operation on a database. This code crashs if I run 3 async operations, but if it's only one there is no problem. How to organize multi threaded operation on SQLite? I have tried QMutex.lock but It did not work.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>
#include <database.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
Database *db0=new Database();
Database *db1=new Database();
Database *db2=new Database();

QString param0="Select LastUpdateDate From TableLastUpdateLog Where TableName='T1'";
 QString param1="Select LastUpdateDate From TableLastUpdateLog Where TableName='T2'";
  QString param2="Select LastUpdateDate From TableLastUpdateLog Where TableName='T3'";


QtConcurrent::run(db0,&Database::Select,param0);
QtConcurrent::run(db1,&Database::Select,param1);
QtConcurrent::run(db2,&Database::Select,param2);



return app.exec();
```

}

**database.cpp**

```
void Database::Select(QString query) {

m_db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","myconn");
m_db.setDatabaseName("./mytask.db");
bool result=m_db.open();
if(result==false)
    qDebug()<<"Failed";
else
{
    qDebug()<<"Connection is Success";
    m_qry=new QSqlQuery(m_db);
    m_qry->exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    m_qry->exec("DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=2");
    m_qry->prepare(query);
    if(m_qry->exec()!=true)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Query Failed:"<<m_qry->lastError();
        qDebug()<<m_qry->lastQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        QSqlRecord rec=m_qry->record();
        while(m_qry->next())
        {
            qDebug()<<m_qry->value("LastUpdateDate").toDateTime();
        }

    }
}

m_db.close();
m_db.removeDatabase("myconn");

//mutex.unlock();   
}
```

Comment: missing : `Database` class definition and `Database::Select` definition

Comment: @UmNyobe I have added Database::Select

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes because you are still ***using the same connection to access the database*** from each thread. In Qt connections are identified by their names, ie the value "myconn" passed to `addDatabase`.

Not only Qt will misbehave, but sqlite driver too. From Qt docs

```
Warning: If you add a connection with the same name as an existing connection, 
the new connection replaces the old one.
```

Your statement `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2` allow multithreading as long as [no two threads attempt to use the same database connection](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html), which is not the case.

The solution is to provide a different connection name for each of your objects.